# adding custom Direcitves to Custom libraries

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a custom library. where a custom Directive should be imported!! and everything is fine!! custom Directive is not implemented

```
@Directive({

    selector:'[demo-dir]',
})
export class DemoDirective{

constructor(private elref:ElementRef,private Renderer:Renderer2){

}
@HostListener('click') mouseover()
{

    alert("test")
    console.log("test")
}
ngOnInit()
{
this.Renderer.setStyle(this.elref.nativeElement,'color','red');
}
```

Custom library module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DemoComponent } from './demo.component';
import { DemoDirective } from './demo.directive';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [DemoComponent,DemoDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[DemoComponent]
})
export class DemoModule { }
```

and I have imported my custom library module in  app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive you have written is fine, you did not export the `DemoDirective` directive from the `DemoModule`  module:

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [DemoComponent, DemoDirective],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports:[DemoComponent, DemoDirective]
})
export class DemoModule { }
```

Without exporting the directive, it is not visible in other components even if you import the `DemoModule`.